# How to fine tune a Huggingface Seq2Seq model with a dataset from the hub?

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface

I want to train the `"flax-community/t5-large-wikisplit"` model with the `"dxiao/requirements-ner-id"` dataset. (Just for some experiments)

I think my general procedure is not correct, but I don't know how to go further.

My Code:

Load tokenizer and model:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM, AutoModel
checkpoint = "flax-community/t5-large-wikisplit"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(checkpoint)
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(checkpoint).cuda()
```

Load dataset that I want to train:

```
from datasets import load_dataset
raw_dataset = load_dataset("dxiao/requirements-ner-id")
```

The raw_dataset looks like this ['id', 'tokens', 'tags', 'ner_tags']

I want to get the sentences as sentence and not as tokens.

```
def tokenToString(tokenarray):
  string = tokenarray[0]
  for x in tokenarray[1:]:
    string += " " + x
  return string

def sentence_function(example):
  return {"sentence" :  tokenToString(example["tokens"]),
          "simplefiedSentence" : tokenToString(example["tokens"]).replace("The", "XXXXXXXXXXX")}

wikisplit_req_set = raw_dataset.map(sentence_function)
wikisplit_req_set
```

I tried to restructure the dataset such that it looks like the wikisplit dataset:

```
simple1dataset = wikisplit_req_set.remove_columns(['id', 'tags', 'ner_tags', 'tokens']);
complexdataset = wikisplit_req_set.remove_columns(['id', 'tags', 'ner_tags', 'tokens']);
complexdataset["train"] = complexdataset["train"].add_column("simple_sentence_1",simple1dataset["train"]["sentence"]).add_column("simple_sentence_2",simple1dataset["train"]["simplefiedSentence"])
complexdataset["test"] = complexdataset["test"].add_column("simple_sentence_1",simple1dataset["test"]["sentence"]).add_column("simple_sentence_2",simple1dataset["test"]["simplefiedSentence"])
complexdataset["validation"] = complexdataset["validation"].add_column("simple_sentence_1",simple1dataset["validation"]["sentence"]).add_column("simple_sentence_2",simple1dataset["validation"]["simplefiedSentence"])
trainingDataSet = complexdataset.rename_column("sentence", "complex_sentence")
trainingDataSet
```

Tokenize it:

```
def tokenize_function(example):
    model_inputs = tokenizer(example["complex_sentence"],truncation=True, padding=True)
    targetS1 = tokenizer(example["simple_sentence_1"],truncation=True, padding=True)
    targetS2 = tokenizer(example["simple_sentence_2"],truncation=True, padding=True)
    model_inputs['simple_sentence_1'] = targetS1['input_ids']
    model_inputs['simple_sentence_2'] = targetS2['input_ids']
    model_inputs['decoder_input_ids'] = targetS2['input_ids']
    return model_inputs

tokenized_datasets = trainingDataSet.map(tokenize_function, batched=True)
tokenized_datasets=tokenized_datasets.remove_columns("complex_sentence")
tokenized_datasets=tokenized_datasets.remove_columns("simple_sentence_1")
tokenized_datasets=tokenized_datasets.remove_columns("simple_sentence_2")
tokenized_datasets=tokenized_datasets.remove_columns("simplefiedSentence")
tokenized_datasets
```

DataLoader:

```
from transformers import DataCollatorForLanguageModeling
data_collator = DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(tokenizer, mlm=False)
data_collator
```

Training:

```
from transformers import Seq2SeqTrainer, Seq2SeqTrainingArguments, TrainingArguments, EvalPrediction, DataCollatorWithPadding, Trainer

bleu = evaluate.load("bleu")

training_args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(
  output_dir = "/",
  log_level = "error",
  num_train_epochs = 0.25,
  learning_rate = 5e-4,
  lr_scheduler_type = "linear",
  warmup_steps = 50,
  optim = "adafactor",
  weight_decay = 0.01,
  per_device_train_batch_size = 1,
  per_device_eval_batch_size = 1,
  gradient_accumulation_steps = 16,
  evaluation_strategy = "steps",
  eval_steps = 50,
  predict_with_generate=True,
  generation_max_length = 128,
  save_steps = 500,
  logging_steps = 10,
  push_to_hub = False,
  auto_find_batch_size=True
)

trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
    model,
    training_args,
    train_dataset=tokenized_datasets["train"],
    eval_dataset=tokenized_datasets["validation"],
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    compute_metrics=bleu,

)
trainer.train()
```

The Problem is, that I do not understand how the model know the expected value and how it calculate its loss. Can someone give me some ideas what happens where?

I hope some one can help me understand my own code, because the documentation by Hugging Face does not help me enough. Maybe someone have some Codeexamples or something else. I do not completely understand how I fine tune the model and how I get the parameters the model expects to train it. I also do not understand how the training works and what the parameters do.

Comment: Print out what the datasets contains, understand how `datasets.Dataset` works and how the `transformers.Trainer` object works, then finally understand what `flax-community/t5-large-wikisplit` expects in its `forward()` function. After that you would understand the current code you have.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## TL;DR

Take some time to go through https://huggingface.co/course/ or read the https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/natural-language-processing/9781098136789/

After that, you would have answered most of the questions you're having.

**Show me the code:** Scroll down the bottom of the answer =)

---

### What is a `datasets.Dataset` and `datasets.DatasetDict`?

TL;DR, basically we want to look through it and give us a dictionary of keys of name of the tensors that the model will consume, and the values are actual tensors so that the models can uses in its `.forward()` function.

In code, you want the processed dataset to be able to do this:

```py
from datasets import load_dataset

ds = load_dataset(...)
ds.map(func_to_preprocess)

for data in ds:
    model(data)  # Does a forward propagation pass.
```

#### Why can't I just feed the `Dataset` into the model directly?

It's because the individual datasets creators/maintainers are not necessary the ones that create the models.

And keeping them independent makes sense since **a dataset can be used by different model and each model requires different datasets to be preprocessed/"munge"/"manipulated" to the format that it expects** (kind of like the Extract, Transform, Load (ETL) process in transformers-based models).

Unless explicitly preprocessed, most datasets are in raw text (`str`) and annotation/label format, which usually are of these types:

- single token decoder output (single token label),

  - e.g. Language ID task `[in]: Hallo Welt` and `[out]: de`
  - normally uses `AutoModelForSequenceClassification`
- regression float output

  - e.g. Textual Similarity `[in]: Hello world <sep> Foo bar` and `[out]: 32.12`
  - normally uses `AutoModelForSequenceClassification`
- free-form autoregressive decoder output (a natural text sentence, i.e. a list of tokens)

  - e.g. Machine Translation `[in]: Hallo Welt` and `[out]: Hello World`
  - normally uses `AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM`
- fixed tokens decoder output (a list of labels)

  - e.g. BIO anntoations `[in]: Obama is the president` and `[out]: ['B-PER', 'O', 'O', 'O']`
  - normally uses `AutoModelForTokenClassification`

For the dataset you're interested in:

```
from datasets import load_dataset

raw_dataset = load_dataset("dxiao/requirements-ner-id")
raw_dataset['train'][0]
```

[out]:

```
{'id': 0,
 'tokens': ['The',
  'operating',
  'humidity',
  'shall',
  'be',
  'between',
  '0.4',
  'and',
  '0.6'],
 'tags': ['O',
  'B-ATTR',
  'I-ATTR',
  'O',
  'B-ACT',
  'B-RELOP',
  'B-QUANT',
  'O',
  'B-QUANT'],
 'ner_tags': [0, 3, 4, 0, 1, 5, 7, 0, 7]}
```

But the model doesn't understand inputs and outputs, it only understand `torch.tensor` objects, hence you need to do some processing.

#### So tokenizers usually expects raw strings, not list of tokens.

Normally, a model's tokenizer converts raw strings into a list of token ids,

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM, AutoModel

model_name = "flax-community/t5-large-wikisplit"

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(model_name)

tokenizer(["hello world", "foo bar is a sentence", "fizz buzz"])
```

[out]:

```
{'input_ids': [[21820, 296, 1], [5575, 32, 1207, 19, 3, 9, 7142, 1], [361, 5271, 15886, 1]], 'attention_mask': [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]}
```

#### But my dataset comes pre-tokenized? So what do I do?

```
sentences = [
['The', 'operating','humidity','shall','be','between','0.4','and','0.6'],
['The', 'CIS', 'CNET', 'shall', 'accommodate', 'a', 'bandwidth', 'of', 'at', 'least', '24.0575', 'Gbps', 'to', 'the', 'Computer', 'Room', '.']
]

[tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(sent) for sent in sentences]
```

[out]:

```
[[634, 2, 2, 2, 346, 24829, 22776, 232, 22787],
 [634, 21134, 2, 2, 2, 9, 2, 858, 144, 2, 2, 2, 235, 532, 2, 2, 5]]
```

##### Why are there so many tokens with index 2?

Because they are unknowns. If we take a look at the vocab,

```
>>> tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokenizer.unk_token)
2
```

#### Then how do I encode the tags or new tokens?

Here's an example:

```
from itertools import chain

from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM, AutoModel
from datasets import load_dataset


model_name = "flax-community/t5-large-wikisplit"

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(model_name)

raw_dataset = load_dataset("dxiao/requirements-ner-id")



# Get the NER tags.
tag_set = list(map(str, set(chain(*raw_dataset['train']['tags']))))

# Put them into the tokenizer.
tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'additional_special_tokens': tag_set})

train_datset = raw_dataset['train'].map(lambda x: 
    {'input_ids': tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(x['tokens']),
     'labels': tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(x['tags'])}
)


valid_datset = raw_dataset['validation'].map(lambda x: 
    {'input_ids': tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(x['tokens']), 
     'labels': tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(x['tags'])}
)
```

#### How to train a Seq2Seq using the text inputs and the NER labels as the outputs?

**TL;DR:**

```
from itertools import chain

from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM, AutoModel
from transformers import Seq2SeqTrainingArguments, Seq2SeqTrainer
from datasets import load_dataset
import evaluate

model_name = "flax-community/t5-large-wikisplit"

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(model_name)



raw_dataset = load_dataset("dxiao/requirements-ner-id")


# Get the NER tags.
tag_set = list(map(str, set(chain(*raw_dataset['train']['tags']))))

# Put them into the tokenizer.
tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'additional_special_tokens': tag_set})

train_data = raw_dataset['train'].map(lambda x: 
    {'input_ids': tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(x['tokens']),
     'labels': tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(x['tags'])}
)


valid_data = raw_dataset['validation'].map(lambda x: 
    {'input_ids': tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(x['tokens']), 
     'labels': tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(x['tags'])}
)

# set special tokens, not sure if it's needed but adding them for sanity...
model.config.eos_token_id = tokenizer.eos_token_id
model.config.pad_token_id = tokenizer.pad_token_id


mt_metrics = evaluate.combine(
    ["bleu", "chrf"], force_prefix=True
)

def compute_metrics(pred):
    labels_ids = pred.label_ids
    pred_ids = pred.predictions
    
    predictions = tokenizer.batch_decode(pred_ids, skip_special_tokens=True)

    labels_ids[labels_ids == -100] = tokenizer.pad_token_id
    references = tokenizer.batch_decode(labels_ids, skip_special_tokens=True)

    outputs = mt_metrics.compute(predictions=predictions,
                             references=references)

    return outputs

training_args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(
    output_dir='./',
    per_device_train_batch_size=4,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=4,
    logging_steps=1,
    save_steps=5,
    eval_steps=1,
    max_steps=10,
    evaluation_strategy="steps",
    predict_with_generate=True,
    report_to=None,
    metric_for_best_model="chr_f_score",
    load_best_model_at_end=True
)

trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_data.with_format("torch"),
    eval_dataset=valid_data.with_format("torch"),
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics
)

trainer.train()
```

Hey, something seems fishy, when we train an NER, shouldn't we be using `AutoModelForTokenClassification` not `AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM`?

Yeah, but like many things in life, there's many means to get to the same end. So in this case, you can take the liberty and be creative to do, e.g.

- https://paperswithcode.com/paper/dont-classify-translate-multi-level-e/review/
- https://aclanthology.org/2022.vardial-1.9/

#### Περίμενε ένα λεπτό! (Wait a minute!) That's not what I want to do!

I guess you don't really want to do NER but the lessons learnt from munging the corpus with additional tokens and the `.map` functions should help what you need.

#### Why don't you just tell me how to manipulate the `DatasetDict` so that it fits what I need?!

Alright, alright. Here goes...

First, I guess you would need to clarify in your question what task are you tackling on top of what model and dataset you're using.

From your code, I am guessing you are trying to build a model for

- **Task: Text simplification**

  - `[in]: This is super long sentence that has lots of no meaning words.`
  - `[out]: This is a long-winded sentence.`
- **Model: Seq2Seq**

  - Using `AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM("flax-community/t5-large-wikisplit")`
- **Dataset: Texts from `dxiao/requirements-ner-id`**

  - `[in]: ['The', 'operating','humidity','shall','be',...,]`
  - `[out]: 'The humidity is high'`
  - Only the input tokens from `dxiao/requirements-ner-id` are use as input texts, everything else in the dataset is not needed
- **Preprocessing: Convert the input into a simplified version**

  - `[in]: ['The', 'operating','humidity','shall','be',...,]`
  - `[out]: ['The', 'XXXXX', 'humidity', ...]`
  - Convert the simplified output and original inputs to `input_ids` and `labels` (that the model expects)
  - Lets create a `random_xxx` function for this purpose.

```
def random_xxx(tokens):
    # Pick out 3 tokens to XXX.
    to_xxx = set(random.sample(range(len(tokens)), 3))
    tokens = []
    for i, tok in enumerate(tokens):
        if i in to_xxx:
            tokens.append('<xxx>')
        else:
            tokens.append(tok)
    return tokens
```

##### So how do I do what you listed above? Stop stalling, just give me the code...

```
from itertools import chain
import random

import os
os.environ["WANDB_DISABLED"] = "true"

from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM, AutoModel
from transformers import Seq2SeqTrainingArguments, Seq2SeqTrainer
from datasets import load_dataset
import evaluate

model_name = "flax-community/t5-large-wikisplit"

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(model_name)


def random_xxx(tokens):
    # Pick out 3 tokens to XXX.
    to_xxx = set(random.sample(range(len(tokens)), 3))
    tokens = []
    for i, tok in enumerate(tokens):
        if i in to_xxx:
            tokens.append('<xxx>')
        else:
            tokens.append(tok)
    return tokens

raw_dataset = load_dataset("dxiao/requirements-ner-id")

# Put '<xxx>' into the tokenizer.
tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'additional_special_tokens': ['<xxx>']})

# Assuming `input_ids` is "complex" original sentence.
# and `labels` is "simplified" sentence with XXX

train_data = raw_dataset['train'].map(lambda x: 
    {'input_ids': tokenizer(" ".join(x['tokens']),
                            max_length=40, truncation=True, padding="max_length")["input_ids"],
     'labels': tokenizer(" ".join(random_xxx(x['tokens'])), 
                         max_length=40, truncation=True, padding="max_length")["input_ids"]}
)


valid_data = raw_dataset['validation'].map(lambda x: 
    {'input_ids': tokenizer(" ".join(x['tokens']),
                            max_length=40, truncation=True, padding="max_length")["input_ids"],
     'labels': tokenizer(" ".join(random_xxx(x['tokens'])), 
                         max_length=40, truncation=True, padding="max_length")["input_ids"]}
)
    
# set special tokens, not sure if it's needed but adding them for sanity...
model.config.eos_token_id = tokenizer.eos_token_id
model.config.pad_token_id = tokenizer.pad_token_id


mt_metrics = evaluate.combine(
    ["bleu", "chrf"], force_prefix=True
)

def compute_metrics(pred):
    labels_ids = pred.label_ids
    pred_ids = pred.predictions
    
    predictions = tokenizer.batch_decode(pred_ids, skip_special_tokens=True)

    labels_ids[labels_ids == -100] = tokenizer.pad_token_id
    references = tokenizer.batch_decode(labels_ids, skip_special_tokens=True)

    outputs = mt_metrics.compute(predictions=predictions,
                             references=references)

    return outputs

training_args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(
    output_dir='./',
    per_device_train_batch_size=4,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=4,
    logging_steps=1,
    save_steps=5,
    eval_steps=1,
    max_steps=10,
    evaluation_strategy="steps",
    predict_with_generate=True,
    report_to=None,
    metric_for_best_model="chr_f_score",
    load_best_model_at_end=True
)

trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_data.with_format("torch"),
    eval_dataset=valid_data.with_format("torch"),
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics
)

trainer.train()
```

Here's a few other tutorials that will I find helpful:

- Take some time to go through https://huggingface.co/course/ or read the https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/natural-language-processing/9781098136789/

  - It would really help answer most of the questions you'll have and be more confident that you understand what you're typing in code.
- https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/tutorial
- https://www.kaggle.com/code/alvations/from-datasets-import-datasetdict
- https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/how-to-efficiently-convert-a-large-parallel-corpus-to-a-huggingface-dataset-to-train-an-encoderdecodermodel/24788
- https://www.kaggle.com/code/alvations/huggingface-earlystopping-callbacks

Comment: Very nice answer. I got a question, why combine `["bleu", "chrf"]`? I am working on translation task, and I just use BLEU. Is that alright?

Comment: Because https://aclanthology.org/W18-6319/ =)